# How can I access Swagger UI on my AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, swagger-ui, amazon-eks

I am very new to the AWS world and have recently been tasked with transferring a Web API from a traditional server set up to AWS. This has involved the following steps:

1. Creating a new EKS cluster using eksctl
2. Creating an ECR repository
3. Publishing the Docker image of the ASP.NET Web API to the repo
4. Configure service and deployment YAML
5. Deploy application using kubectl
6. Access Web API application using Load Balancer URL

The above steps have been successful. However I am having trouble accessing Swagger UI from the Load Balancer URL. Swagger UI was running successfully locally from the Docker image in VS2022. But I get a 404 when trying to resolve the same URL appended to the Load Balancer URL (see the image).

What additional steps are required for Swagger UI to execute from the aforementioned application setup?

Here are the YAML files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ekstest2
  labels:
    app: ekstest2
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ekstest2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ekstest2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ekstest2
        image: xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ekstest2:ekstest2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ekstest2
  labels : 
    app  : ekstest2
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: ekstest2
  type : LoadBalancer
```

[image: Swagger 404]

Comment: If you SSH to the worker node hosting the docker image, are you able to curl and get the swagger page?

Comment: What is the port which is associated with your loadbalancer service? If it is not 80, then you need to add that port number in your URL.

Comment: Please share your deployment and service yamls, this way community will help you quickly identify if there are any inconsistencies within.

Comment: Added the YAML files to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Port number is 80:32093/TCP

Comment: Thank you. I'm not really sure on which `path` it should work. What happens if you hit loadbalancer URL without `swagger/index.html`? I don't see any ingresses or anything. So URL is exactly as it's in the browser. And it should work on port `80` unless an application doesn't listen to another port.

Comment: @moonkotte - Trying the Loadbalancer URL without the swagger/index.html returns a 404.

Comment: `Swagger UI was running successfully locally from the Docker image in VS2022` How exactly did you access it? You may need to create another pod within your k8s cluster and test connectivity with `curl` to figure out if it actually works.